# How do I send custom claims from Azure AD to Azure B2C?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I currently have Azure AD set up as an identity service provider on my Azure AD B2C tenant. I am trying to pass additional claims to my Azure AD B2C application however, it is not receiving the claims.

[Additional Claims](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzIEG.png)

When setting up my flow to use AD there is a mapping for claims, how do I map these additional claims shown above?
[Claims Mappings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QB6eT.png)

I've tried adding the additional claims to the application manifest in both my AD and AD B2C tenants.